# Use of unresolved identifier userDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What is causing this to happen? the two instances of this error apear at the very bottom of my view controller in which the lines start with "userDefaults". here is my code

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController : UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

var aRandomDate = NSDate()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    dateLabel.text = strDate
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true;
}

@IBAction func Save(sender: UIButton) {
    var t = EventSaver(pEventName: "Drinking Coffee", pEventDate: aRandomDate )

    let encodedEventName = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(t.EventName)
    let encodedEventDate = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(t.EventDate)

    var encodedArray: [NSData] = [encodedEventName,]


    userDefaults.setObject(encodedArray, forKey: "Event")
    userDefaults.synchronize()


    println("saved")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it like this:

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: UIButton) {
var t = EventSaver(pEventName: "Drinking Coffee", pEventDate: aRandomDate )

var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 

let encodedEventName = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(t.EventName)
let encodedEventDate = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(t.EventDate)

var encodedArray: [NSData] = [encodedEventName,]


userDefaults.setObject(encodedArray, forKey: "Event")
userDefaults.synchronize()


println("saved")


}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you haven't declared the constant userDefaults.
Add the following line before you set the encodedArray object in the userDefaults:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't declaring userDefauts

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```